# TypeError: string indices must be integers while extracting the keys

Tags: python

Dictionary is as the following

```
my = {
  "1": {
    "first": 'A,B',
    "column": "value",
    "test":"test",
    "output": "Out1",
    "second": "Cost",
    "Out2": "Rev"
  },
  "2": {
    "first": 'None',
    "column": "value",
    "test":"test",
    "output": "Out2",
    "Out2": "Rev"
  }
}
```

Code I tried is the following

```
{k:{l:l[i] for i in ['first','test'] for l,m in v.items()} for k,v in my.items()}
```

I am trying to extract only two `['first','test']` keys, there is a change of `['first','test']` not exist also.

I am getting

> TypeError: string indices must be integers. WHat is the problem with code

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: That 1-liner is trying to be too clever for my liking. It's not easy to understand at all. It's also broken, apparently

Comment: You can apply [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) which will be a bit slightly faster than iterating over whole dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take one of the subdictionaries to understand what is going wrong here.

```
  "1": {
    "first": 'A,B',
    "column": "value",
    "test":"test",
    "output": "Out1",
    "second": "Cost",
    "Out2": "Rev"
  },
```

```
{k:{l:l[i] for i in ['first','test'] for l,m in v.items()} for k,v in my.items()}
```

The variable `k` in your code will be the key `"1"` and the value `v` will be the subdictionary.

Then, when you do `"l"`, `"l"` is actually the dictionary keys which are strings e.g. `"first"`, `"test"`. Then, when you try doing `l:l[i]`, you are actually trying to index the string `"first"` and you aren't using an integer value to index the string but you are passing a string value - so you are doing `"first"["first"]`.

That is why you see a `TypeError` with the message "string indices must be integers".

If you want a clever one liner, this should work

```
{
   key: {sub_key:sub_dict[sub_key] for sub_key in ["first", "test"]}
   for key, sub_dict in my.items()
}
```

Personally, I would write

```
selected_dict = dict()
for key, value in my.items():
    for sub_key in ["first", "test"]:
        selected_dict[sub_key] = value[sub_key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of them could work:

```
print({k: {"first": v["first"], "test": v["test"]} for k, v in my.items()})
print({k: {i: v[i] for i in ['first','test']} for k, v in my.items()})
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected

```
print({x: {i: y[i] for i in ['first', 'test']} for x, y in my.items()})
```

output

```
{'1': {'first': 'A,B', 'test': 'test'}, '2': {'first': 'None', 'test': 'test'}}
```